# Cannot start a war with a tomcat

Tags: tomcat, war

does anyone could start that war with a tomcat?
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5FiAsl5yGbZcV9rZDBrVS1IcDA/edit

I put the war in webapps, startup.bat, http://localhost:8080/org.cap.editor.jsp/edit.html in browser but I get an "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/org.cap.editor.jsp/edit.html" it's missing the edit.html?

If anyone can start this, please tell me how, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML files you mentioned are not packaged in the war file(You can open it with 7zip/winrar or something like that to see for yourself). When building the application into the war file make sure your HTML files are packaged, they should be located in the root map alongside the WEB-INF and META-INF in the war.